# Query on using output

Tags: php, output

New Problem: Now my menu can only print out 1 page's name when i have 2 pages. Worst still, if i did not have that extra $two = find_Condition() at the most bottom code of "The Page" it would not even go to the content. But when i use that, it can only show the content of the first page but print out the name of the second page.

I am new to php, so I do not know how to use output. Currently I am using a file with css and all. But the moment I add in my php to emulate the html tags and everything the page ends up being blank and white.

edit: Alright i changed to echo. However, im unable to print out the content which is the last php code at the bottom of "The Page" for some reason.

The content in the last php has to follow a certain format as im using a css. 
the format is like this: the first div has to take in the id of the file name, for e.g. abscess followed by the content and 3 end div.

Format of the content in the last php

```
<div class="bb-item" id="abscess">
<div class="content">
<div class="scroller">

Content

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The Page

```
        function find_condition() {

        global $connection;

        $query = "SELECT * ";
        $query .= "FROM pages ";
        $query .= "WHERE visible = 1 ";
        $query .= "AND subject_id = 2 ";
        $query .= "ORDER BY position ASC";
        $page_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        confirm_query($page_set);
        return $page_set;
        }


        $two = find_condition();
            while($page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($two)) {   

                $pagearray = $page['menu_name'];


                ?>


                <ul id="menu-toc" class="menu-toc">
                    <li class="menu-toc-current">               
                    <a href="abscess">ABSCESS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="apthous ulcer">APTHOUS ULCER</a></li>
                    <li><a href="bad breath">BAD BREATH</a></li>
                     <li><a href="bleeding gums">BLEEDING GUMS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="caries">CARIES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="cosmetic dentistry">COSMETIC DENTISTRY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="cracked tooth">CRACKED TOOTH</a></li>
                    <li><a href="crowns and bridges">CROWNS & BRIDGES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="dental implants">DENTAL IMPLANTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="discolored teeth">DISCOLORED TEETH</a></li>


                    <li><a href="impacted wisdom tooth">IMPACTED WISDOM TOOTH</a></li>
                    <li><a href="toothache">TOOTHACHE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="tooth decay">TOOTH DECAY</a></li>

<?php

        $output = "<li>";
        $output .= "<a href=\"";
            $output .= $pagearray;
                $output .= "\">";
                    $output .= $pagearray;
                    $output .= "</a></li>";
                    }
                    echo $output;


                    ?>


                </ul>

            </div>


            <div class="bb-custom-wrapper">
                <div id="bb-bookblock" class="bb-bookblock">
                <?php require_once("abscess.php"); ?>
                    <?php require_once("apthousulcer.php"); ?>
                    <?php require_once("bad breath.php"); ?>
                    <?php require_once("bleeding gums.php"); ?>
                    <?php require_once("caries.php"); ?>
                    <?php require_once("cosmetic dentistry.php"); ?>
                    <?php require_once("Cracked Tooth.php"); ?>
                    <?php require_once("crowns & bridges.php"); ?>
                    <?php require_once("dental implants.php"); ?>
                    <?php require_once("discolored teeth.php"); ?>
                    <?php require_once("impacted wisdom teeth.php"); ?>
                    <?php require_once("toothache.php"); ?>
                    <?php require_once("tooth decay.php"); ?>


                    <?php
        $two= find_condition();
         while($page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($two)) {

        $pagearray = $page['menu_name'];
        $content = $page['content'];

        $output .= "<div class=\"bb-item\" id=\"";
        $output .= $pagearray;
        $output .= "\">";
        $output .= "<div class=\"content\">";
        $output .= "<div class=\"scroller\">";
        $output .= "<h2>";
        $output .= $pagearray;
        $output .= "</h2>";
        $output .= $content;
        $output .= "</div>";
        $output .= "</div>";
        $output .= "</div>";
        }
        echo $output;
        ?>
```

Comment: what is $two, and it value

Comment: it is just the function find_condition at the top which i just assign it to the variable $two. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only function can return value.. you have return in while loop which is wrong. instead you can use echo to print.

it should be like follow

```
  while($page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($two)) {   

            $pagearray = $page['menu_name'];
            $content = $page['content'];
                    $output = "<li>";
                    $output .= "<a href=\"";
                    $output .= $pagearray;
                    $output .= "\">";
                    $output .= $pagearray;
                    $output .= "</a></li>";
                    }
                    echo $output;


                    ?>
```

Comment: Could you please expand on your answer a bit?

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer it works well. Unfortunately now i have a new problem. I have editted the post to show the problem. My new coding cause only 1 menu page to show up when i have 2. The content shows only the first page's content. I suspect it is due to the reinitializing of $two, but if i dont use it, the bottom code wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

replace it in your code

```
 $return_value = find_condition();
if($return_value!="")
{
    while($page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($return_value)) 
   {   
        //your all code with html
   }
}
```